# CSS not working in IE but works in Chrome

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am trying to alternate table row colors by odd and even rows. Seems simple and it works fine in chrome but when I test in IE nothing changes. The weirdest thing is, it originally did work in IE, but suddenly stopped and I can't get it to work again. Here is the CSS I am using.  Any ideas why this wouldn't be working?

```
.styleIntr {
white-space: nowrap;
margin-top: 5px;
background-color: #DFF0F9;
margin-bottom: 5px;
border: 1px solid #CCC;
height: 320px;
z-index: 1;
font-size: 9pt;
color: #000;
padding-left: 50px;
padding-right: 50px;
}
   .styleIntr tr:nth-child(odd) td{
    background: #DFF0F9;
    }
    .styleIntr tr:nth-child(even) td{
    background: #EFF7FB;
    }
```

here is the HTML:

```
<table class="styleIntr" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" rules="rows" frame="hsides" align="right"
width="10%">            

<TBODY><TR>
<TD style="HEIGHT: 20px"><SPAN id=Label3>Time</SPAN> </TD>
<TD style="HEIGHT: 20px"><SPAN id=Label4>Type</SPAN> </TD>
<TD style="HEIGHT: 20px"><SPAN id=Label5>Type 1</SPAN> </TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD align=center style="HEIGHT: 20px">09:00 </TD>
<TD align=center style="HEIGHT: 20px">S </TD>
<TD align=center style="HEIGHT: 20px">B </TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD colSpan=3>&nbsp; </TD></TR>
</TBODY>
    </table>
```

Comment: IE 7-8 doesn't support the `nth-child` pseudo selector. Their support starts with IE9 http://caniuse.com/#search=nth-child

Comment: @Dekel -- it does [per MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child).

Comment: You can use the [Selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/) JS library to have CSS3 support in IE.

Comment: @anied, check the update on my comment. hit the `enter` too fast :)

Comment: @Dekel -- gotcha.

Comment: @SJR59, the question is which version of IE you check this

Comment: I added my HTML . I have IE11

Comment: @SJR59 -- might be helpful to get the generated markup as well.

Comment: In your example you only have odd (direct) childs (because of the use of the ItemTemplate). Please post the generated HTML, and not the ASP code.

Comment: You say it used to work. In that case, go back to an earlier version using the source code control system you are using, until you find a version that works. Then you can track down in which version you introduced the bug. If you are using `git`, then you can use `git bisect`.

Comment: Version control won't help because I never got to check in my changes.

Comment: @BramVanroy i will put in the generated html now

Comment: I tested your code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/xmvbm2zz/) and it works fine in IE11. There must be something else wrong. Maybe try clearing your cache as well.

Comment: I cleared my cache and even tried rebooting my machine, but nothing seems to working. Any other ideas?

Comment: If the same html used to work, but not any more, check if IE now renders the page in compatibility mode.

Comment: @MrLister how do I check that? When I look at the css generated by IE the odd and even features don't show up. Only the main styleIntr class and inline styles. any possible explanation for this?

Comment: @SJR59 Easiest is to press F12 and see if the document mode is "Edge". If it isn't, the browser is in one of its compatibility modes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can trying to alternate table row colors by odd and even rows but your style is incorrect you have add this css to rows td. so remove td like this
First Use this

```
<style>
   .styleIntr tr:nth-child(odd){
    background: #DFF0F9;
    }
    .styleIntr tr:nth-child(even){
    background: #EFF7FB;
    }
</style>
```

OR

If IE8 doesn't support the nth-child
use this code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".styleIntr tr:nth-child(even)").addClass("even");
    $(".styleIntr tr:nth-child(odd)").addClass("odd");
});
</script>
<style>
   .styleIntr tr.odd{
    background: #DFF0F9;
    }
    .styleIntr tr.even{
    background: #EFF7FB;
    }
</style>
```

you can check this fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/foku4qa3/

If IE does not support then use this one.

```
<table class="styleIntr" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" rules="rows" frame="hsides" align="right"
width="10%">            

<TBODY><TR>
<TD style="HEIGHT: 20px"><SPAN id=Label3>Time</SPAN> </TD>
<TD style="HEIGHT: 20px"><SPAN id=Label4>Type</SPAN> </TD>
<TD style="HEIGHT: 20px"><SPAN id=Label5>Type 1</SPAN> </TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD align=center style="HEIGHT: 20px">09:00 </TD>
<TD align=center style="HEIGHT: 20px">S </TD>
<TD align=center style="HEIGHT: 20px">B </TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD colSpan=3>&nbsp; </TD></TR>
</TBODY>
    </table>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".styleIntr tr:odd").addClass("odd");
    $(".styleIntr tr:even").addClass("even");
});
</script>
<style>
   .styleIntr tr:nth-child(odd){
    background: #DFF0F9;
    }
    .styleIntr tr:nth-child(even){
    background: #EFF7FB;
    }
    .styleIntr tr.odd{
    background: #DFF0F9;
    }
    .styleIntr tr.even{
    background: #EFF7FB;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: I tried both of these methods but neither of them seem to be working. I am really not sure why because its identical to the jsfiddle...I am so confused!

Comment: When I look at the css generated by IE the odd and even features don't show up. Only the main styleIntr class and inline styles. any possible explanation for this?

Comment: Sorry to keep commenting but I found something very interesting out. When I run my program and emulate IE to an older version and then switch back everything works. It almost like IE reboots and realizes there is CSS there...

Comment: IE version is the problem. none if these methods work in IE 8 or lower. The moment I switch to IE 9 my original method works.

Comment: Sorry for late replay pls use this jQuery                                                  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".styleIntr tr:odd").addClass("even");
    $(".styleIntr tr:even").addClass("odd");
});